# Create a model with a foreign key to a table not created by SQLAlchemy

Tags: mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, mysql-connector

My flask app has a table that I created using mysqlconnector:

```
import mysql.connector
from .config import host, user, passwd, db_name

connection_pool = mysql.connector.pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(
    pool_size=8,
    host=host,
    user=user,
    password=passwd,
    database=db_name)
connection_object = connection_pool.get_connection()
cursor = connection_object.cursor(buffered=True)

cursor.execute(
            """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable (
                ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
            )"""
connection_object.commit()
```

A library that I'm importing (authlib) connects to the same DB using SQL

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from authlib.integrations.sqla_oauth2 import OAuth2ClientMixin

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://user:pwd@host/db'
db = SQLAlchemy (app)

class OAuth2Client(db.Model, OAuth2ClientMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'oauth2_client'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    smthg_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('MyTable.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    smthg = db.relationship('MyTable')

client = OAuth2Client()
db.session.add (client)
db.session.commit()
```

During execution, it raises this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper mapped class OAuth2Client->oauth2_client, expression 'MyTable' failed to locate a name ("name 'MyTable' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class '__main__.OAuth2Client'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.
```

How can I create a table in SQL Alchemy that contains such a foreign key?

Comment: A solution that gets it done is to not create foreign keys using SqlAlchemy, but rather add them with raw 'ALTER TABLE' SQL queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SQLAlchemy's [reflection](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/reflection.html?highlight=reflection#reflecting-database-objects) capabilities to create a [Table](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table) instance for the existing class, and then assign the instance to a model's `__table__` attribute:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

...

# Load the existing table into the db object's metadata
mytable = sa.Table('MyTable', db.metadata, autoload_with=db.engine)


# Create a model over the table.
class MyTable(db.Model):
    __table__ = mytable
```

Now `MyTable` can be successfully referenced from within the `OAuth2Client` model.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `autoload=True` is now considered obsolete, and just `autoload_with=db.engine` is sufficient.

Comment: @GordThompson you're quite right, `autoload_with` is enough, and `autoload` is deprecated in 1.4 (although it still appears in the example in the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/reflection.html#reflecting-database-objects)

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I have submitted a [patch](https://gerrit.sqlalchemy.org/c/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/+/2414) to update the documentation.